# Writing Unit Tests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I am new to using the Visual Studio Code in place of visual studios and i feel a little lost to how i can set up my program to include unit test.

I created a c# console app and i would like to create a test file in which i can test my main program for the console app. I am reading about all these extensions documents but i am not getting what i am expecting. 
I created a test extension which i have added to my main app folder. Any helpful tips to how i can integrate unit tests the same way/similar that was done in visual studios.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can write the same way as you do in Visual Studio. For testing the code run `dotnet test` in command line.

see the following link for unit tests: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/articles/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test

Comment: Thanks - i am looking into it now but a quick question will have to write tests  with just Mocha Framework?

Comment: If I understand you correct you want to test c# console app with mocha framework? I think this won't work because mocha is  a test framework for javascript and therefore will not work with c#.

Comment: Thanks the article helped a lot - i had to follow the tutorial before i can redo based on my needs.

Comment: How do you set breakpoints and debug tests in VS Code?

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien Please look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging. Somewhere below the page there is a section about setting (conditional) breakpoints; click on the editor margin / left side of the line number to add breakpoints. After you have launched debugging it should hit when the line is reached.